# looking for option to locate icon in element

Tags: java, selenium

I tried to check if the eye icon is at the TAB title here, is there way to find it?

here is the image of the [DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9uh4.jpg) 
the locator i have till now is to the element itself but not to the eye icon

```
.map-tab--active span
```

OR

```
//span[@class="business-in-area"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Share url please

Comment: @Sers [URL](https://maps.b144.co.il/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get image url using `getComputedStyle`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

driver.get("https://maps.b144.co.il/");

WebElement icon = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.business-in-area")));
String iconUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':before').getPropertyValue('content');", icon);
```

Result:

> url("https://maps.b144.co.il/images/icons/f80af126.white_eye_icon.png")

TestNG Assert:

```
Assert.assertEquals(iconUrl, "url(\"https://maps.b144.co.il/images/icons/f80af126.white_eye_icon.png\")");
```

Comment: What is .business-in-area and span.business-in-area? they are the same CSS locator?
and these is what it called pseudo element? how you get into it?
Thank you

Comment: `span.business-in-area` css selector to get span element. pseudo element content getted JavaScript and `window.getComputedStyle`. You can read about pseudo elements in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: is there any difference between the selectors? `span.business-in-area` `.business-in-area` and why such thing like : `driver.findElement(elem).getCssValue("content")` won't work?

Comment: There's no difference between those selectors in this case. You can use both. If you use `getCssValue("content")` and will get `normal`, that is css style for the `.business-in-area` element but not for pseudo. You have to do iti with `getComputedStyle(element, '::before')` JS code. See some examples [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/)

Comment: You can use a bit simpler code `js.executeScript("return getComputedStyle(arguments[0], '::before').content", icon)`. Tested with Chrome

Comment: Thanks, so i understand that it depends on the value you search for, plus it depends on the JS that you are using to find the pseudo element?
Plus you need to know well CSS, isn't it?